# AmazonS3Client: jar file corrupted on download from s3

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am trying to download a jar file using `AmazonS3Client`. But upon download, the jar file obtained is corrupted is not executed.

I am using the following program:

```
    String existingBucketName = args[0];
    String keyName = "/" + "EMRS3Files-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar";

    BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("access-key", "secret-key");
    AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCreds);

    GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest(existingBucketName, keyName);
    S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(request);
    S3ObjectInputStream objectContent = object.getObjectContent();

    IOUtils.copy(objectContent, new FileOutputStream("/tmp/abc.jar"));
```

On running the `/tmp/abc.jar` file, I get the following error:

```
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile abc.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked:

```
    GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest(existingBucketName, keyName);
    S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(request);
    S3ObjectInputStream objectContent = object.getObjectContent();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/abc.jar");

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

    int buf = 0;
    while((buf = objectContent.read(buffer)) > 0)
    {
        fos.write(buffer, 0, buf);
    }
    fos.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried downloading it manually (with a browser) and then running it?

It may be AmazonS3 somehow corrupted it, not your program.

Comment: @nish hmm. I don't know then. Sorry.