# Unable to download a jar file from AmazonS3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jar

I'm trying to download a jar file from S3 using the approach of this accepted answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32822091/6532976

But I'm getting this error:

```
Error:(61, 36) java: constructor GetObjectRequest in class com.amazonaws.services.mediastoredata.model.GetObjectRequest cannot be applied to given types; required: no arguments found: java.lang.String,java.lang.String reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

I understand that GetObjectRequest doesn't require any arguments but I've found some online examples on how to use GetObjectRequest such as this:
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest which clearly passed parameters to GetObjectRequest.

So, which is the correct procedure to download a JAR file from S3?

Edit: My code which is causing the error

```
    AWSCredentials myCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(access_key, secret_key);
    AmazonS3Client s3Client;
    s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(myCredentials);


    GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest(bucketname, jarFilePathInBucket);
    S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(request);
    S3ObjectInputStream objectContent = object.getObjectContent();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pathToJarFile);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

    int buf = 0;
    while((buf = objectContent.read(buffer)) > 0)
    {
        fos.write(buffer, 0, buf);
    }
    fos.close();
```

Comment: Please post an [mcve] of the code that **you** used. Don't link to other questions- SO questions need to be self-contained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't yet posted your code, but there really isn't an alternative for this.

The AWS3 Java client libraries contain **2** classes named `GetObjectRequest`. When you `import` the class, you need to ensure that you take the right one.

1. `com.amazonaws.services.mediastoredata.model.GetObjectRequest`
2. **`com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest`** <-- this is the correct one

The other class that's also called GetObjectRequest takes no constructor arguments. The one that you need has multiple overloaded constructors, including one overload that takes 2 Strings.

At the top of your file, you'll need to have a line that says

```
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest
```

Comment: Thanks! I was importing the wrong Class the whole time :)